# JavaScript: Multiple Persistent Index Variables

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, scope

I'm new to the wold of programming and have run into a bit of trouble making a photo gallery with JS.

So, the thumbnails invoke a modal with the appropriate image that is passed via an index as parameter. I've used a bit of JQuery just to attach handler on all the thumbnails without looping.

The very first Modal initialization works fine, I'm able to switch between images and then close the modal just fine. After that if I reinitialize the modal, the first image appears correct but when using the "Next" and "Previous" buttons another image appears in the modal. After closer inspection (and a bunch of variable logs) I've determined that the old index (from the first modal initialization) persists within the program thus the function is running the previous index and the new one passed to it. The more times you close it the more index variables you have. It almost seems like the function is running multiple copies of itself and appending all those images onto that one modal.

Sorry if this is a very obvious mistake. I don't really post on this forum but try to solve it myself however after like 6 hours and 50 Chrome tabs, I'm just about done. Thanks a lot! Here's my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/5yejqw8a/4/#&togetherjs=M77M8B8LU8

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.GalleryImg').on('click', function() { //Attach event handler on each photo
    var GalleryImgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('GalleryImg')); //Turns object array to an a proper array
    var ImgIndex = GalleryImgs.indexOf(this); //Position of img clicked
    OpenModal(ImgIndex); //Passes the index into the modal function
  });

  function OpenModal(n) { //Modal function with index parameter
    var SlideIndex = n;
    console.log("Start Index = "+SlideIndex);
    var Lightbox = document.getElementById("Lightbox");
    var Modal = document.getElementById("ModalContent");
    var Slides = document.getElementsByClassName("ModalSlides");

    Lightbox.style.display = "block";
    Slides[SlideIndex].style.display = "block";

    var PreviousBtn = document.getElementById("PreviousBtn");
    PreviousBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (SlideIndex > 0) {
        Slides[SlideIndex].style.display = "none";
        SlideIndex --;
        Slides[SlideIndex].style.display = "block";
        console.log("PCurrent = "+SlideIndex);
      } else {
        return;
      };
    });

    var NextBtn = document.getElementById("NextBtn");
    NextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      if (SlideIndex < Slides.length-1) {
        console.log(SlideIndex);
        Slides[SlideIndex].style.display = "none";
        SlideIndex ++;
        Slides[SlideIndex].style.display = "block";
        console.log("NCurrent = "+SlideIndex);
      } else {
        return;
      };
    });

    var CloseBtn = document.getElementById("CloseBtn");
    CloseBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      Lightbox.style.display = "none";
      var i = 0;
      while (i < Slides.length) {
        Slides[i].style.display = "none";
        i++
      };
      console.log("Closing Index = "+SlideIndex);
    });

  };

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that because of this structure:

```
function OpenModal(n) {
  var PreviousBtn = document.getElementById("PreviousBtn");
  PreviousBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // ...
  });

  var NextBtn = document.getElementById("NextBtn");
  NextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // ...
  });

  var CloseBtn = document.getElementById("CloseBtn");
  CloseBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // ...
  });
}
```

Each time `OpenModal` is called, it is adding **new event listeners** to `PreviousBtn`, `NextBtn` and `CloseBtn`. So the more you click, the more functions are to be called by the listeners.

Here is an example:

```js
var activate = document.getElementById("activate");

activate.addEventListener("click", event => {
  var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
  var result = document.getElementById("result");
  let i = 0;
  result.textContent = "";
  
  submit.addEventListener("click", event => {
    result.textContent += ' ' + i++;
  });
});
```

```css
body { background: #fafafa }

#result, #hint {
  font-family: fantasy;
  background: #def;
  padding: .5em;
}

#result {
  background: #fde;
  height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<div id="hint">
  Click on activate, then click submit many times. 
  <br> Click activate again and click submit again many times.
</div>
<div id="result">Result will come here.</div>
<button id="activate">Activate</button>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

In the snippet, if you activate then submit five times, and repeat doing that four times, you get :

> 0 1 2 3 4
>   5 0 6 1 7 2 8 3 9 4
>   10 5 0 11 6 1 12 7 2 13 8 3 14 9 4
>   15 10 5 0 16 11 6 1 17 12 7 2 18 13 8 3 19 14 9 4

because every time `activate` is clicked, a new listener is added with a new `i`.

So what you should have is:

```
var PreviousBtn = document.getElementById("PreviousBtn");
PreviousBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // ...
});

var NextBtn = document.getElementById("NextBtn");
NextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // ...
});

var CloseBtn = document.getElementById("CloseBtn");
CloseBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // ...
});

function OpenModal(n) {
  // ...  
}
```

That way, the listener is added only once.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are adding every time a new listener to PreviousBtn, NextBtn and CloseBtn. You need to define the listeners them outside the OpenModal function or use every time [`removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener) (which doesn't make any sense) for every event listener you defined.

A good possible way could be this:

```js
// Gallery Lightbox
$(document).ready(function(){
 
  var SlideIndex = 0;
  var Lightbox = document.getElementById("Lightbox");
  var Modal = document.getElementById("ModalContent");
  var Slides = document.getElementsByClassName("ModalSlides");
    
  $('.GalleryImg').on('click', function() { //Attach event handler on each photo
    var GalleryImgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('GalleryImg')); //Turns object array to an a proper array
    var ImgIndex = GalleryImgs.indexOf(this); //Position of img clicked
    SlideIndex = ImgIndex; //Passes the index into the modal function
    
    Lightbox.style.display = "block";
    Slides[SlideIndex].style.display = "block";

  });

  
  var PreviousBtn = document.getElementById("PreviousBtn");
  PreviousBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (SlideIndex > 0) {
      Slides[SlideIndex].style.display = "none";
      SlideIndex --;
      Slides[SlideIndex].style.display = "block";
      console.log("PCurrent = "+SlideIndex);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });

  var NextBtn = document.getElementById("NextBtn");
  NextBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (SlideIndex < Slides.length-1) {
      console.log(SlideIndex);
      Slides[SlideIndex].style.display = "none";
      SlideIndex ++;
      Slides[SlideIndex].style.display = "block";
      console.log("NCurrent = "+SlideIndex);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  });

  var CloseBtn = document.getElementById("CloseBtn");
  CloseBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    Lightbox.style.display = "none";
    var i = 0;
    while (i < Slides.length) {
      Slides[i].style.display = "none";
      i++
    }
    console.log("Closing Index = "+SlideIndex);
  });

});
```

```css
/* Gallery */
.Gallery {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.GalleryImg {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.Gallery img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.07);
}
/* Lightbox */
#Lightbox {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 5%;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  overflow: auto;
}

#ModalContent {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.ModalSlides {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#CloseBtn {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  z-index: 999;
}

#CloseBtn:hover,
#CloseBtn:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#NextBtn, #PreviousBtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: -75px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

#NextBtn {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

#NextBtn:hover,
#PreviousBtn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Gallery">
                <div class="row mt-3">
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <img class="GalleryImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <img class="GalleryImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x150" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <img class="GalleryImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x150" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-3">
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <img class="GalleryImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/390x150" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <img class="GalleryImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x50" alt="">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-4">
                    <img class="GalleryImg" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="">
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div id="Lightbox">
                <span id="CloseBtn">&times;</span>

                <div id="ModalContent">
                  <img class="ModalSlides" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="">
                  <img class="ModalSlides" src="http://via.placeholder.com/380x150" alt="">
                  <img class="ModalSlides" src="http://via.placeholder.com/450x150" alt="">
                  <img class="ModalSlides" src="http://via.placeholder.com/390x150" alt="">
                  <img class="ModalSlides" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x50" alt="">
                  <img class="ModalSlides" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x250" alt="">
                  <a id="PreviousBtn">&#10094;</a>
                  <a id="NextBtn">&#10095;</a>
                </div>
              </div>
```

In this way we have defined only one time the event listeners.
`SlideIndex`, `Lightbox`, `Modal` and `Slides` variables are defined at the begin.